# Laravel downloads not working and page loads forever

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using `Barryvdh/DomPDF`  package to download a page as PDF but whenever I click on the button to download, the page loads forever and nothing downloads. I am then forced to restart my computer. I don't whats causing this.

**My View:**

```
<a href="{{url('finance/invoice/printPdf/'.$detail->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Download PDF</a>
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function printPdf($id){
        //Print this page in PDF
        $details = DB::select("select a.id as id, b.name as subsidiary, c.name as client, due_date, invoice_date, invoice_number, order_number,
        sub_total, tax, grand_total, notes from sys_invoices as a, sys_organizations as b, sys_clients as c
        where a.subsidiary_id = b.id and a.client_id = c.id and a.id = '$id'");
        //Get items
        $items = DB::select("select * from sys_items where invoice_id = '$id'");
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.invoice', compact('details', 'items'));
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: Does the PDF have images?

Comment: No. There are no images

Comment: use dompdf and check their documendation